# Stop websites from forcing cursor to their search box?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, focus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I keep Google from stealing my cursor? (Firefox)](https://superuser.com/questions/28481/can-i-keep-google-from-stealing-my-cursor-firefox)

It really annoys me when sites like msn.com try to force your cursor to their search box.

I have msn.com as my home page since I like the content. But sometimes I'm just not that interested in looking around the site and want to go to my URL bar straight away and start typing an address.

It is so annoying that as I try to type in an address half of it ends up in the search box.

I am using Firefox, so is there a plugin that I can use? I not sure but could that Greasemonkey do it?

Comment: Sounds like the same problem solved here: http://superuser.com/questions/28481/can-i-keep-google-from-stealing-my-cursor-firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using javascript .focus(). Probably something along these lines;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function formfocus() {
      document.getElementById('element').focus();
   }
   window.onload = formfocus;
</script>
```

Disabling javascript prevented this. (Tested on Firefox using NoScript plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't really prevent this from happening, until websites start using the HTML5 `autofocus` attribute. Once they start doing this, you should be able to tweak a setting in your web browser to disable it.